# Implementing GridView Event - Selecting A Row

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am a .NET newbie who is currently adding to existing cod. I have a telerik RadGrid - which inherits events from .NET's standard GridView control.

Here is the markup in the aspx file:

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="GridViewSelector" SkinID="GridViewSelectorSkin" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="12" AllowSorting="True" EnableViewState="true" 
    AllowCustomPaging="true" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="false" style="float:left;"
    AllowMultiRowEdit="false" OnNeedDataSource="GridViewSelector_NeedDataSource"
    OnItemCommand="GridViewSelector_ItemCommand" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" OnItemCreated="GridViewSelector_ItemCreated"
    OnSortCommand="GridViewSelector_SortCommand" 
    OnItemDataBound="GridViewSelector_ItemDataBound" 
    OnPreRender="GridViewSelector_PreRender">
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

How do I assign an event handler method to listen to when a row has been selected?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this I think.

```
protected void RadGrid1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       GridDataItem item =(GridDataItem )RadGrid1.SelectedItems[0];//get selected row
   }
```

Comment: I've done that but I keep getting this error: does not contain a definition for 'GridViewSelector_SelectIndexChanged -> I have implemented the event handler in the aspx.cs page sitting behind the .aspx page with the gridview but get this error - makes no sense!